# Triggers for Opt-Out List

Tags: mysql

Never used triggers before.  Just want to make sure I am doing the right thing and not messing up my DB.  I wanted to use a trigger to keep an opt out list.  So the trigger would be when I insert a new number into my 'Opt-Out' Table, then it would delete that number from my DB.  How does this look?

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER `trigger_opt_out` AFTER INSERT 
    ON DB.opt_out 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        UPDATE TABLE DB.table t 
                JOIN opt_out o 
                ON t.fax=o.fax 
                SET t.fax = NULL

   END;
```

I do not want to delete the whole record just the fax number and/or telephone number.

Is it possible to make the trigger delete the number from multiple tables? Or would I just have to create another trigger?

I have read about the overhead that triggers cost.  Does the trigger only cause a loss of efficiency in the table that it is on, in my example, would the overhead only be on my opt_out table, or would it also effect the table(s) that I targeted as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to join. Use

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_opt_out` AFTER INSERT ON DB.opt_out 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        UPDATE DB.table
        SET fax = NULL
        WHERE fax = NEW.fax;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

And of course when you update a table this will reduce read performance on that table depending on your lock strategy.

Comment: Little unclear about the 'NEW' from WHERE fax=NEW.fax.  How does that work?  Will that work outside of triggers as well?  I have been using joins a lot, I am guessing that this WHERE is faster. Thanks!

Comment: `NEW` references the record that was inserted in the `opt_out` table. That record contains the `fax` value you want to remove from the other table. And no, this will not work outside the trigger.